# How to link button click action to TypeScript code?

Tags: typescript

With JavaScript, you typically do this to handle button clicks:

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="myClickHandler">Click!</button>
```

where in the JavaScript code you have:

```js
function myClickHandler { /* some action */ }
```

In my TypeScript code, I have an application class MyApp (in MyApp.ts):

```
class MyApp
{
  myClickHandler() { /* some action */ }
}
```

and I have this in my main main.ts file:

```
let myApp = new MyApp();
```

I would like to reference myApp in the onclick statement for the button, but that doesn't work:

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="myApp.myClickHandler">Click!</button>
```

When I explicitly link up the event handler in code, it works:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = () => { myApp.myClickHandler(); }
```

So, my question is: how do I hook up the button click event handler to the member function of my MyApp class instance from within the HTML code?

(I know I should probably use a framework for these things, and I'll be moving on to React later, but I'd like to get this right first)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically OK but I would:

- not use `let` for a global variable (`myApp`)
- define `myClickHandler` as an arrow function (just as in your `onClick` override)

  ```
  class MyApp {
      myClickHandler = (): void => { /* some code */ }
   }
  ```

Comment: The problem seems to be that (even when I use var instead of let), I get an error saying: JavaScript runtime error: 'myApp' is undefined.